# Hide <span> until <div> is hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I made this a couple of months back, but now I'm going through and re-tuning it. It's an image at the bottom of the page that when clicked it brings you to the top using JavaScript.

I already have the HTML, CSS and JS finished. But I can't get the CSS to work properly. I want a little message ("Scroll To Top") to remain hidden until the  is hovered over, where it will appear.

I tried making a presentation here with JSFiddle, but it doesn't seem to want to work. (http://jsfiddle.net/9jvuoxra/1/)

Additionally Today I decided I want the image to become a background-image of the , but I can't get the  to work correctly with {display: block;}. I've gotten it to work on other files in the past, but it doesn't want to work.

```
<!-- Scroll to the top option -->

<script>
 function scroll () {
  window.scrollTo (0, 0);
 };
</script>

<div id="scroll-to-top">
 <a onclick="scroll ()">
  <span>Scroll To Top</span>
  <img src="img/scroll-to-top.png" alt="Scroll To Top" title="Return to top">
 </a>
</div>

<style>
 div#scroll-to-top {margin-left: auto; width: 42px; height: 42px;}
 div#scroll-to-top a {color: #ffffff;}
 div#scroll-to-top a span {visibility: hidden;}
 div#scroll-to-top a:hover span {visibility: visibile;}
 div#scroll-to-top span {position: absolute; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px; width: 42px; font-size: 10px; text-align: center;}
 div#scroll-to-top img {display: block; width: 42px; height: 42px;}
 div#scroll-to-top img:hover {cursor: pointer;}
</style>
```

Comment: scroll() is a DOM function, so scroll() has no arguments. Call yours something else.

Comment: "Scroll To Top" hover effect: there's a little typo error. It's "visible" not "visibile".

Comment: Also, if you are going to use an inline event handler in jsFiddle, you need to export it, e.g. `window.scroll = scroll;`. If you do that, your Fiddle works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scroll(X, Y)` is already a defined javascript function, which is now replaced by the identical function `scrollTo(X, Y)`, so using `scroll()` might not work always (as it is not working on jsfiddle). Instead you could write `<a onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0)">` to make it work.

For hiding the span, you may use jQuery.

**Make sure to remove the visibility: hidden attribute also.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide the span
    $('#scroll-to-top span').hide();

    // bind the hover event (mouseenter) to show the span and
    // next hover event (mouseleave) to hide again
    $('#scroll-to-top').hover(function(){
        $('#scroll-to-top span').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#scroll-to-top span').hide();
    });

});
```